# Symfony - Authentication lost after redirection

Tags: symfony, session, authentication, token, provider

I'm facing a problem with my Symfony project.

I have two Symfony apps (let's call them A and B) who can communicate with each other by Web Service. In one of them (app A), I store my list of users, and I'm trying to authenticate an user through app B.
The expected behavior is :
- User enters his username and password
- App B gets the username/password
- App B calls App A through a WS, asking if this user is OK
- If user OK, App B creates a session token and authentifies the user.

At the moment, I'm able to authenticate my user, but every time I navigate through app B, I lose my session token (so I'm redirected to my /login page).
The weird thing is that I'm still authenticated, but the session token doesn't contain my User object anymore (it contains a User object with every attribute "null").

Here is my security.yml :

```
providers:
    webservice:
        id: webservice_user_provider

firewalls:
    login:
        pattern: ^/login$|^/check$|^/_wdt
        anonymous: true
    secured:
        pattern: ^/
        anonymous: false
        form_login:
            check_path: /login_check
            login_path: login
            username_parameter:  username
            password_parameter:  password
            default_target_path: /
        logout:
            path:   logout

access_control:
```

My LoginController (app B) :
    public function checkAction(Request $request)
    {
        // Récupération du login et du mot de passe dans les paramètres de la requête
        if ($request->getMethod() == "POST")
        {
            $username = $request->get("username");
            $password = $request->get("password");

```
        // Interrogation du repo pour savoir si l'utilisateur existe
        $repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("EntrepotEntitiesBundle:Utilisateurecommercant");

        /* @var $repo \Entrepot\EntitiesBundle\Repository\UtilisateurecommercantRepository */
        $user = $repo->findByLoginAndPassword($username, $password);

        if ($user != null) // On a retrouvé un utilisateur => OK
        {
            // On sérialise alors un token de connexion dans la session
            $this->login($request, $user);
            return $this->indexAction();
        }
    }

    return $this->render('EntrepotUtilisateurBundle::index.html.twig', array(
        'last_username' => $this->getRequest()->getSession()->get(SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME),
    ));
}


public function login(Request $request, UserInterface $user)
{
    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, $user->getPassword(), 'secured', $user->getRoles());
    $request->getSession()->set('_security_secured', serialize($token));
    $this->get("security.context")->setToken($token);

    // Et on lève un évènement "login"
    $event = new InteractiveLoginEvent($request, $token);
    $this->get("event_dispatcher")->dispatch("security.interactive_login", $event);
}
```

One thing I don't understand, is when and how the `checkAction()` should be called. At this moment, it is only called when my user validates his login form. Should it be called every time I try to navigate to a new page ? I don't really understand how it works, and I'd like to understand it better...

Did I forget something ?

Thanks.

Comment: `checkAction()` is used exactly like you said i.e: it shouldn't be called every time.about the firewall I had a similar problem, and it was solved by sharing the context of the firewalls.read http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html : common pitfalls.However I don't know how that translates to a WS authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to solve my problem using this link :

http://blog.vandenbrand.org/2012/06/19/symfony2-authentication-provider-authenticate-against-webservice/

Well explained, I understood very well and I'm now able to authenticate an user through my WS :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the provider key for your form_login i.e:

```
form_login:
    ...
    provider: webservice
```